# SQL Trigger for Chinook database: condition when sum is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, conditional-statements

I am brushing up on my SQL and using the Chinook database for practice.

the data model can be found here: https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chinook_Schema&referringTitle=Documentation

The goal is to write a trigger so that the Total in the Invoice table is updated when I insert or delete invoicelines.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTotal ON InvoiceLine
AFTER INSERT, DELETE
AS
    UPDATE Invoice
    SET Total = (
        SELECT sum(LineSum) AS InvoiceTotal
        FROM (
            SELECT InvoiceId, (UnitPrice * Quantity) AS LineSum 
            FROM InvoiceLine 
        ) AS WithLineSum
        GROUP BY InvoiceId
        HAVING WithLineSum.InvoiceId = Invoice.InvoiceId
    )
```

and this works great when I insert and delete invoiceline records, except for when I delete the very last invoiceline for an invoice. When I do that, i get the error:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Total', table 'Chinook.dbo.Invoice'; column does not allow nulls. 
UPDATE fails.

so basically I need to set it to zero if sum(LineSum) is null

I am struggling to figure out how to structure the conditional, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is inefficient as you are updating every Invoice every time instead of only those affected by the operation. You need to leverage the special [Inserted and Deleted tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) within the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateTotal ON InvoiceLine
AFTER INSERT, DELETE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Inv
    SET Total = Total + (i.UnitPrice * i.Quantity)
        FROM Inserted i
            INNER JOIN Invoice Inv
                ON i.InvoiceId = Inv.InvoiceId;

    UPDATE Inv
    SET Total = Total - (d.UnitPrice * d.Quantity)
        FROM Deleted d
            INNER JOIN Invoice Inv
                ON d.InvoiceId = Inv.InvoiceId;
```

Comment: @user3689167: I just tested this on my local machine and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your subquery in a COALESCE, basically

```
SET Total = COALESCE(...subquery..., 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This trigger is going to update every invoice which you do not want to do every time one record changes. You need to look at the pseudotables inserted and deleted to update only invoices which were changed.

Next, consider not using correlated subqueries. You need trigger code to be the fastest possible and an update using joins is liikely to be faster (Test of course)

Finally you can use coalesce on your sum so that if it is null, it will update the sume to zero.